# How to a publish visual studio solution with two dependencies projects to azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

In Visual studio 2013 I have MVC solution with two projects:
project 1
project 2

project 1 depends on project 2

It works fine in my local machine but I get error when I deployed to Azure:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.
```

My question: did I have to deploy both projects separately to azure or just deploy the main project?

Comment: It looks like your main project doesn't have a reference to MySql.Data, but does have a reference to project 2.

Comment: Did you add the reference to MySql.Data via NuGet or via a file on your local machine? Looks like the latter, in which case I suggest you add the NuGet package instead.

Comment: I build solution based on this article: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider     It's work perfect on my PC but I get error when publishing to Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work automatically but beware of any libraries you have registered in the GAC on your PC since they will automatically link to the GAC version and "Copy Local" in the properties will be set to false. You can change this to true and force it to put a copy in the bin folder so that it copies correctly.

You only need to do this on the project that directly references the file. If project2 references project1, it will copy all output dlls across to bin automatically.

Comment: Thanks for this Answer but where can i change :"You can change this to true and force it to put a copy in the bin folder so that it copies correctly"?.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me to fix this. I noticed that MySql.Data have different versions in the two project. I updated the old one to last version. and It's work. many thanks!